# How to add json object with $(form).serialize()?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, serialization

I have the following code

```
var values = {'value1' : 'one','value2' : 'two'};

...
...
submitHandler:function(form,e){
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: $(form).serialize(),
 });
}
```

I tried with `append method` like below

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();
      var value = {'test' : 'test'};
      formData.append(value);
      $.ajax({
        url : '',
        type : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : formData,
        .....
```

But it shows  **append is not a function**.
Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. `serialize()` creates a form-url-encoded string, where as `FormData` is an collection of the form values, and `value` is an object...? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Oh..! Then I want to create a json object which includes form data and value object into it. Sorry,I thought serialize will make the form data to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will return a query string so use,

```
formData+='&test=test';
```

Code,

```
var formData = $(form).serialize(); // its a string
formData+='&test=test'; // append in string
$.ajax({
    url : '',
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : formData,
    .....
```

And to append value in an object use

```
formData['test']='test';
```

Code,

```
var formData = {'value1' : 'one','value2' : 'two'}; // its an object
formData['test']='test';
$.ajax({
   url : '',
   type : 'post',
   dataType : 'json',
   data : formData,
    .....
```